# (root) Additional property monitor is not allowed - Docker compose

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, yaml

i wanted to run this java app through docker:
https://github.com/ByteHamster/PSE

the docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
simulation:
  build: .
  dockerfile: simulationDockerfile
  environment:
    - DISPLAY
  expose:
    - 12868
    - 12869
    - 12870
    - 12871
  volumes:
    - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix

monitor:
  build: .
  dockerfile: monitorDockerfile
  environment:
    - DISPLAY
  volumes:
    - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
  links:
    - simulation
```

when i run docker-compose build i get this error message:
(root) Additional property monitor is not allowed

what is the valid yml to make this program run?

thanks guys

Comment: That looks like you're using the original ("version 1") Compose format, but current versions of Docker assume files are the current ("version 3") format.  Does adding a leading line `version: '3.8'` and then putting this existing content under a `services:` block make it work?  Also see [Compose file version 3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) in the Docker documentation for details on the file format.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '2'

services:
  simulation:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: simulationDockerfile
    environment:
      - DISPLAY
    expose:
      - 12868
      - 12869
      - 12870
      - 12871
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix

  monitor:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: monitorDockerfile
    environment:
      - DISPLAY
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
    links:
      - simulation
```

had to make the following changes so make it work

thanks @David Maze

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing with other peoples who can have a similar problem.
Check the spaces before names.

```
version: '2'    
services:
  simulation:
    build:
      context:
      dockerfile: simulationDockerfile
    environment:
      - DISPLAY
    expose:
      - 12868
      - 12869
      - 12870
      - 12871
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix

monitor:  <-- check the spaces before names
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: monitorDockerfile
    environment:
      - DISPLAY
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
    links:
      - simulation
```